# How to read multiple columns in while loop?

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new to bash and programming. And now want to create a bash script that will check if the port is listening in the pod with netstat the second/third/forth... column of the file with multiple ports separated by tab and then output should look something like that:

```
nameofthepod:
############################################
port[status OK|Error], port[status OK|Error]
```

Example the columns in the file:

```
nameofthepod    12    23    45
nameofthepodwithdiffname(loonger)    154     24    65
pod(shorter)    90     54    15

#!/bin/bash
while IFS=$'\t' read -r pod port1 port2 port3 port4 port5 port6 port7 port8
do
   echo "$pod":
   echo "########################################################"
   sudo kubectl exec -t "$pod" -- bash -c "netstat -tulnp | grep ':$port1\|$port2\|$port3\|$port4\|$port5\|$port6\|$port7\|$port8'"
 if [ $? -eq 0 ]
         then
           echo "Port status for $port1|$port2|$port3|$port4|$port5|$port6|$port7|$port8 OK"
         else
           echo "Port status ended with an ERROR for $port1|$port2|$port3|$port4|$port5|$port6|$port7|$port8"
   fi

done < pods_and_ports
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome! Analyze your script in shellcheck.net first

Comment: I know that syntax is incorrect. I'm trying to get help with even how the script should work, the syntax check is going to be the next step.

Comment: If you provide a script with correct syntax, people could easily try it out, modify and help you.

Comment: The syntax is now ok, but still, I'm stuck with these port* vars, I think there's a way to do it the right way

Comment: You can read into an array `IFS=$'\t' read -r -a port` and then excract `pod` like `pod=${port[1]};` and remove first array element with something along `port=("${port[@]:1}")` and use `( IFS='|' echo "${port[*]}" )` to join array elements with a `|`. But for me it's still unclear what is your question. Why are you asking how to read two columns, your script looks quite ok and seems to read like 9 columns from a file at a time, more then two, so why are you asking about two??

Comment: my bad, haven't updated the header, but yeah it's for a few ports Thank you!

Comment: A good question is about a specific problem you encountered while writing your code. You're showing us your code, you're describing what you want it to do, but I don't see a narrow, specific problem you encountered while trying to make it do that thing described.

Comment: (note the "minimal" part of the [mre] definition -- showing more code than the shortest segment that lets someone reproduce the specific issue you ran into is often counterproductive, as it distracts from that error).